# Is there such a functional programming idiom?

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

```
fun <I, O> ((I) -> O).modify(modifier: (I, (I) -> O) -> O): (I) -> O =
    { modifier(it, this) }

@Test
fun modify() {
    assertEquals(
        200.0,
        { x: Double -> x + 100.0 }
            .modify { x, parent -> parent(sin(x)*100.0) }(PI/2)
    )
}
```

What I want is to turn a unary function F<sub>1</sub>(x) into another unary function F<sub>2</sub>(x) that uses the first function in some way. Am I reinventing the wheel here? Does this functional operation already have some more specific name than "modify"?

Comment: Looks pretty much like `compose` to me. But why did `modifier` have to accept the input as well as the wrapped function? The gluing code could apply the inner function itself and then pass it to the outer function. This is useful only if the outer function should be allowed to decide whether to apply inner function.

Answer (score 0):

So, in functional, curried syntax that would be

```
modify :: (i -> o) -> (i -> (i -> o) -> o) -> i -> o
modify f modifier x = modifier x f
```

Note that you're not actually using the fact that the second argument of `modifier` is a function, i.e. this is strictly a specialisation of

```
modify :: a -> (i -> a -> o) -> i -> o
modify a modifier x = modifier x a
```

which can be written

```
modify a modifier x = flip modifier a x
```

...allowing us to [η-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion) it to

```
modify a modifier = flip modifier a
```

The flip itself can be flipped too:

```
modify a modifier = flip flip a modifier
```

...and we can η-reduce the rest too:

```
modify = flip flip
```

Whatever this is worth.

On another thought, `(i -> o) -> o` is the characteristic signature of [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), so perhaps that's what you're re-inventing here.

Your test case looks like what you mostly want is a way to pre-process the argument of a function. That, as Marko Topolnik already commented, is simply [composition](https://github.com/MarioAriasC/funKTionale/wiki/Function-composition)

```
assertEquals(
    200.0,
    ({ x: Double -> x + 100.0 }
        compose { x -> sin(x)*100.0 }) (PI/2)
)
```

(Not sure I've got the Kotlin syntax right there)